# Riley Rebus in three parts

Tags: knowledge, rebus

Work out what each image refers to, then combine them to make up another word.
What is that word?

Prefix:
[image: prefix]

Infix:
[image: infix]

Suffix:
[image: suffix]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word is

> HOLIDAY.

Prefix:

> a quick Google search for this image shows me that she's called [Holly Willoughby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holly_Willoughby).

Infix:

> this is clearly a LID.

So we have

> HOLLY and LID, which fit together at the L, and DAY seems like a good choice for the last picture, giving a full answer of HOLIDAY.